# Android application - disable screen lock

Tags: android, settings, display, screen-lock

I am trying to disable automatic screen lock of my phone while application running.
I used the below permissions and code,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

The phone automatic lock is disabled but, the display light is off (which is set the display time out in settings).

How can I enable the display also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` flag to keep the screen on:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```